# Não consigo acessar ip Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Tenho um servidor configurado no Google Cloud hospedando um sistema para testes da empresa. Conseguia acessar normalmente o sistema com o ip e porta 8080 pelo navegador, porém não estou conseguindo mais e o interessante é que só não consigo quando tento de dentro da empresa, fiz testes fora da empresa inclusive utilizando o mesmo provedor de internet e funciona normalmente. Quando troco o ip externo da empresa, o acesso funciona e se troco o ip externo da minha VM no Cloud também funciona, porém depois de um tempo volta a deixar de funcionar. Não consigo nem fazer um ping de dentro da empresa para o ip da VM no Cloud. Alguém aqui usa o Google Cloud e já passou por esse problema, ou tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Bom dia Cara da uma olhada na regra de Firewall pode haver alguma restrição pra o Ip !

Comment: Desculpa pela demora mas conferi as regras de firewall, e não existe restrição para meu ip externo. Resolvi o problema em partes. Descobri que isso acontecia mais quando eu ia configurar uma chave de acesso e fazia várias tentativas de conexão, após algumas tentativas o ip externo era bloqueado, mas pelo que vi, é uma configuração da própria google e não da minha instância.